# How to get multiple versions on angular depending modules

Tags: angular

I'm working in a company and we are many feature teams working on the frontend Angular application organized in modules.
We have upgraded version of Angular to Angular7 but for some modules we would like to keep the previous version of Angular.

Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, if you want to use them in the same project. Why don't you just have different versions of the modules, if you want to keep the old ones for older projects?

Comment: it's the same application / project. Migration to Angular7is not desirable in some of our custome code / modules. We want the same app to run with Angular 6 for some modules and Angular 7 for others

Answer (score 0):

If you speak about [NgModules](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules), I don't think this is possible.

Even if your Angular modules are imported from separated projects, it's the root module who will instanciate and run them. So it will be the root Angular version that matters. In the case an imported module has been written using an older version of Angular, it may encounters deprecations and differences that will not compile.

You will have to maintain difference versions of your modules if you want to upgrade them.