# Using old Angular module in new project and vice-versa

Tags: angular

I have built some [feature module](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules) for Angular project, using older Angular version. Would there be any problem if I import these module into a new Angular project?

And vice-versa, If i would like to build a new feature module, using newer version of Angular and import this module into an older Angular project, should there be any problem?

I looked at some previous questions and see that there is conflicting / no concrete answer has been given

[How to get multiple versions on angular depending modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400406/how-to-get-multiple-versions-on-angular-depending-modules)

[Angular Libraries Monorepo: Is it possible to use different versions for every library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976271/angular-libraries-monorepo-is-it-possible-to-use-different-versions-for-every-l)

[Correct way to package an Angular library to support Angular 8, 9 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620989/correct-way-to-package-an-angular-library-to-support-angular-8-9-and-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular, there can only be one `@angular` set of code in your `node_module`s folder. that means only one version of Angular can be installed with your application.

A solution would be to build the new feature as a component library following this link: [Building an Angular 4 Component Library with the Angular CLI and ng-packagr](https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e)

But the best solution would be to move all your code to the later version.